# Pass URL parameters into the 3rd page of the funnel

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, parameters, parameter-passing

We have a optin page in clickfunnels where we collect user email address & name. This information is passed into the 2nd page of the funnel through URL parameters when the user submits. Like this :

```
"mydomain.com/secondpage?cf_uvid=d1def16b1797acafa8c76348cc250104", here the parameter is "?cf_uvid=d1def16b1797acafa8c76348cc250104".
```

There's a button on the second page only which sends the user to the 3rd page of the funnel. But unfortunately, the parameters don't get passed onto the 3rd page. I need a script or a button code that'll collect the parameters and send it to the 3rd page when someone clicks on it.

Thanks in advance.